# How to draw fill color and alpha blended color both in the same legend square box in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following data

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), station = c("41B001", "41B004", "41B005", "41B006", 
"41B008", "41N043", "41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", "41B001", "41B004", 
"41B005", "41B006", "41B008", "41N043", "41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", 
"41B001", "41B004", "41B005", "41B006", "41B008", "41N043", "41R001", 
"41R002", "41WOL1", "41B001", "41B004", "41B005", "41B006", "41B008", 
"41N043", "41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", "41B001", "41B004", "41B005", 
"41B006", "41B008", "41N043", "41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", "41B001", 
"41B004", "41B005", "41B006", "41B008", "41N043", "41R001", "41R002", 
"41WOL1", "41B001", "41B004", "41B005", "41B006", "41B008", "41N043", 
"41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", "41B001", "41B004", "41B005", "41B006", 
"41B008", "41N043", "41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", "41B001", "41B004", 
"41B005", "41B006", "41B008", "41N043", "41R001", "41R002", "41WOL1", 
"41B001", "41B004", "41B005", "41B006", "41B008", "41N043", "41R001", 
"41R002", "41WOL1"), max = c(NA, 1.091875, 0.960625, 0.960833333333333, 
NA, 1.03625, 1.25375, 1.25714285714286, 1.08375, NA, 1.44, 1.45642857142857, 
1.43375, NA, 1.6975, 1.97928571428571, 1.58785714285714, 1.3475, 
NA, 0.965625, 0.774285714285714, 1.62571428571429, 1.14375, 1.2275, 
1.23714285714286, 0.984285714285714, 0.860714285714286, NA, 1.08285714285714, 
NA, 1.31785714285714, 1.504375, 2.09375, 1.56125, 1.099375, 1.183125, 
NA, 1.11857142857143, NA, 0.787142857142857, 0.989375, 2.08428571428571, 
1.155, 0.86875, 0.8, NA, 0.885714285714286, NA, 0.842857142857143, 
0.993571428571428, 1.91, 0.987857142857143, 0.952857142857143, 
0.838333333333333, NA, 1.51625, NA, 0.374285714285714, 1.26571428571429, 
1.83285714285714, 1.80428571428571, 1.32857142857143, 0.920625, 
0.75875, 1.15071428571429, NA, NA, 0.407857142857143, 1.33714285714286, 
1.49714285714286, 1, 0.866428571428571, 0.952857142857143, 0.806428571428571, 
NA, NA, NA, 3.25428571428571, 1.07285714285714, 1.12642857142857, 
0.878571428571429, 1.12928571428571, 0.970833333333333, NA, NA, 
NA, 2.48785714285714, 1.07928571428571, 1.08642857142857, 0.649166666666667
), yield = c(0, 98.3561643835616, 97.1803652968036, 90.9703196347032, 
0, 98.458904109589, 89.6803652968037, 88.1392694063927, 94.6232876712329, 
0, 96.9406392694064, 96.0958904109589, 89.634703196347, 0, 97.7853881278539, 
91.1073059360731, 89.6917808219178, 88.2876712328767, 0, 97.7686703096539, 
77.4134790528233, 90.4371584699454, 19.6379781420765, 98.4403460837887, 
90.0500910746812, 98.4175774134791, 98.3378870673953, 0, 98.2648401826484, 
0, 90.9474885844749, 97.8881278538813, 97.5799086757991, 88.4703196347032, 
98.3333333333333, 97.8424657534247, 0, 87.7283105022831, 0, 79.2465753424657, 
95.6164383561644, 94.1666666666667, 90.0342465753425, 93.6301369863014, 
93.9041095890411, 0, 90.5479452054795, 0, 85.7876712328767, 72.0662100456621, 
80.4452054794521, 90.8675799086758, 88.4018264840183, 82.6141552511416, 
0, 90.6876138433515, 0, 45.9357923497268, 85.4963570127505, 90.4143897996357, 
87.2495446265938, 88.5359744990892, 90.8697632058288, 58.2534246575342, 
90.296803652968, 0, 0, 0, 87.648401826484, 88.2305936073059, 
87.5570776255708, 89.0867579908676, 90.4908675799087, 87.8424657534247, 
0, 0, 0, 90.5479452054795, 90.148401826484, 52.1232876712329, 
81.5753424657534, 89.4406392694064, 90.3082191780822, 0, 0, 0, 
88.3675799086758, 90.9931506849315, 90.662100456621, 87.0091324200913
), environ = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("Urbain avec très forte influence du trafic", 
"Urbain avec forte influence du trafic", "Urbain avec influence modérée du trafic", 
"Urbain avec faible influence du trafic", "Urbain avec très faible influence du trafic", 
"Industriel avec influence modérée du trafic"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), groups = structure(list(date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2019"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = list(1:9, 10:18, 
    19:27, 28:36, 37:45, 46:54, 55:63, 64:72, 73:81, 82:90)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This data is plotted with the following code

```
ggplot(data = melted_CO_yearly_max_max8h, 
       aes(x = date, y = max, fill = station, alpha = ifelse(yield < 85, 0, 1))) +
  geom_col(width = 0.75, colour = "black", size = 0.5, position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.3, 1), guide = 'none') +
  labs(x = '', y = label_conc) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.margin=margin(t = -0.5, l = -2, unit='line'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

and results in this figure
[image]

As you can notice, alpha blending of 0.3 is applied to barplots whose yield is below 85.

Ideally, each square box in the legend would be split along one diagonal with the fill color in the upper part and the alpha blended color in its lower part. Is it achievable ? Many thanks.

Comment: Not saying it's impossible, but I don't think ggplot2 was designed to support this type of legend, so hacking it would be a fair bit of work. The more basic question here, though, is whether this is even desirable. With a wide range of colours, the change in transparency may not be very distinct anyway.

Comment: Indeed. I found another option to display barplots whose yield is below 85 wihch is much clearer by simply changing their outline colour from black to red.